# Display taxonomy terms and nodes together

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy with some terms and subterms and a content type Product, for example:

- Term1

  - Subterm1A

    - Subterm11
  - Subterm1B
- Term2

  - Subterm2A
  - Subterm2B
  - Subterm2C
- Term3

  - Subterm3A
  - Subterm3B

Products can be assigned in every level of the taxonomy (terms, subterms, etc.).
If I enter in the **Term1** page, I'd like to display a list of the subterms and also the list of Products assigned to **Term1** (subterms and Products are at the same level).
How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Views module.  Views provides a view by default that overrides the taxonomy term paths.  Enable this view (or clone the view if you anticipate making a lot of changes and want to reference the original; then enable the clone).

Then edit the view by adding the relationship **Taxonomy term: Content using Name_of_my_vocabulary**.  You will then be able to add the fields from the product nodes that you want.